# How can I utilize dart's async capabilities to wait for a value between callbacks?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a situation where I have one callback which gives me some output continuously `onUpdate(Details)`, and one callback to track when the signal ends `onComplete()`.

Since `onUpdate` gives me some details, I'm debouncing this call:

```
onUpdate: (details) {
  EasyDebounce.debounce(
      'sigController/onUpdate', Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    state.setDetails(details);
  });
},
```

However, `onComplete` is just a void callback that doesn't give me any details, so I'm relying on `onUpdate` to get this information. However, there is chance (pretty much always) that I'm going to receive a final update from the debounce call after the `onComplete` fires.

How can I best utilize dart's async capabilities to handle this?

Comment: and whats the problem with getting a final update `"after the onComplete fires."`? if you dont want it then add some flag like `bool completed` and set it to `true` inside `onComplete`

Comment: Right now I have two bool, `receivedFinalUpdate` and `receiving`. So I just check those two. But I'm curious if there's some cool way to do it also

Comment: It seems likely to me that it's not that `onUpdate` is firing after `onComplete`, it's that your debouncer inherently adds a delay that causes `setState` to be called after `onComplete`.  If so, then `onComplete` could just immediately call `setState` with the latest `details` and [cancel the debounce operation](https://pub.dev/documentation/easy_debounce/latest/easy_debounce/EasyDebounce/cancel.html).

Comment: I see. I can give that a try. I wish `onComplete` would have just provided the details... :D

Comment: Doesn't seem like that package allows me to invoke the latest, as cancel just removes it without executing.

Comment: Right, you'd unfortunately need to maintain your own reference to the callback (or to the latest `details`).  I've filed https://github.com/magnuswikhog/easy_debounce/issues/7.

Comment: ... and now that issue is already fixed.